# clearInterval seems to be stopping unrelated code

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

```js
let questions = [ 
    {
        title: "Commonly used data types DO NOT include:",
        choices: ["strings", "booleans", "alerts", "numbers"],
        answer: "alerts"
    },
    {
        title: "The condition in an if / else statement is enclosed within ____.",
        choices: ["quotes", "curly brackets", "parentheses", "square brackets"],
        answer: "parentheses"
    }
]

let main = document.getElementById('main');
let content = document.getElementById('content');
let title = document.getElementById('quiz-title');
let instr = document.getElementById('instructions');
let btn = document.getElementById('start-button');
let time = document.getElementById('time');
let h2;
let btns;
let newElement;
let correct;
let questionCounter;
let seconds;

const timer = () => {
    time.textContent = seconds;
    seconds--;
    if (seconds < 0) {
        clearInterval(timerStart);
        questionCounter = 4;
    }
}

var timerStart = setInterval(timer, 1000);

const startQuiz = () => {
    title.style.display = 'none';
    instr.style.display = 'none';
    btn.style.display = 'none';
    questionCounter = 0;
    newElement = document.createElement('h2');
    newElement.textContent = questions[questionCounter].title;
    newElement.id = questionCounter;
    content.appendChild(newElement);
    questions[questionCounter].choices.forEach(function(choice) {
        newElement = document.createElement('button');
        newElement.textContent = choice;
        newElement.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-success btn-block');
        newElement.id = choice;
        content.appendChild(newElement);
    })
    seconds = 10;
    timerStart;
};

const advanceQuestion = () => {
        document.getElementById(`${questionCounter}-answered`).style.display = 'none';
    questionCounter++;
    if (questionCounter < 2) {
        newElement = document.createElement('h2');
        newElement.textContent = questions[questionCounter].title;
        newElement.id = questionCounter;
        content.appendChild(newElement);
        questions[questionCounter].choices.forEach(function(choice) {
            newElement = document.createElement('button');
            newElement.textContent = choice;
            newElement.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-success btn-block');
            newElement.id = choice;
            content.appendChild(newElement);
        })
    } else {
        newElement = document.createElement('h2');
        newElement.textContent = 'Good job!';
        content.appendChild(newElement);
        newElement = document.createElement('p');
        newElement.textContent = `Your score is ${time.innerHTML}`;
        content.appendChild(newElement);
    }
    
}

const checkAnswer = (Event) => {
    if (questions[questionCounter].choices.indexOf(Event.target.id) == -1) {
        return;
    } else {
            newElement = document.createElement('h4');
            newElement.textContent = 'Answered';
            newElement.id = `${questionCounter}-answered`;
            content.appendChild(newElement);
        }
        h2 = document.getElementById(questionCounter)
        h2.style.display = 'none';
        for (let i = 0; i < questions[questionCounter].choices.length; i++) {
            btns = document.getElementById(questions[questionCounter].choices[i]);
            btns.style.display = 'none';
        }
        setTimeout(advanceQuestion, 1000);
}

btn.onclick = startQuiz;
document.onclick = checkAnswer;
```

```css
main {
    text-align: center;
}

section {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn {
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

#timer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h6 id="high-scores">View Highscores</h6>
  <h6 id="timer">Time: <span id="time">0</span></h6>
</header>

<main id="main">
  <section id="content">
    <h1 id="quiz-title">Coding Quiz Challenge</h1>
    <p id="instructions">Try to answer the following code related questions within the time limit. Keep in mind that incorrect answers will penalize your score/time by ten seconds!</p>
    <button  id="start-button" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Begin Quiz</button>
  </section>
</main>
```

I am new to JavaScript and have been tasked with writing a code quiz application (no jQuery allowed). The application works as follows: the questions are loaded one at a time as answered and a question counter is incremented as it goes. Once the question counter hits the threshold, the quiz ends and the score is displayed. I have added a timer and there is no issue if the quiz is finished within the time given but if the timer reaches 0, the whole application stops working after the clearInterval runs.

```
const timer = () => {
time.textContent = seconds;
seconds--;
if (seconds < 0) {
    clearInterval(timerStart);
    questionCounter = 4;
}
}
const timerStart = setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

The timer is set to 75 seconds in the calling function. The application advances based on the onclick method for what it's worth, and that seems to stop taking inputs after the clearInterval() call. I can post the rest of the code if needed but it is a bit verbose as I am new to this.

EDIT

```
const advanceQuestion = () => {
if (correct === false) {
    document.getElementById(`${questionCounter}-incorrect`).style.display = 'none';
} else {
    document.getElementById(`${questionCounter}-correct`).style.display = 'none';
}
questionCounter++;
if (questionCounter < 5) {
    newElement = document.createElement('h2');
    content.appendChild(newElement);
    questions[questionCounter].choices.forEach(function(choice) {
        newElement = document.createElement('button');
        content.appendChild(newElement);
    })
} else {
    newElement = document.createElement('h2');
    newElement.textContent = 'Good job!';
    content.appendChild(newElement);
    newElement = document.createElement('p');
    newElement.textContent = `Your score is ${time.innerHTML}`;
    content.appendChild(newElement);
}

const checkAnswer = (Event) => {
    if (Event.target.id === questions[questionCounter].answer) {
        newElement = document.createElement('h4');
        newElement.textContent = 'Correct!';
        content.appendChild(newElement);
    } else {
        newElement = document.createElement('h4');
        newElement.textContent = 'Incorrect';
        content.appendChild(newElement);
    }
    h2 = document.getElementById(questionCounter)
    h2.style.display = 'none';
    for (let i = 0; i < questions[questionCounter].choices.length; i++) {
        btns = document.getElementById(questions[questionCounter].choices[i]);
        btns.style.display = 'none';
    }
    setTimeout(advanceQuestion, 1000);
}

const startQuiz = () => {
title.style.display = 'none';
questionCounter = 0;
newElement = document.createElement('h2');
content.appendChild(newElement);
questions[questionCounter].choices.forEach(function(choice) {
    newElement = document.createElement('button');
    content.appendChild(newElement);
})
seconds = 10;
timerStart;

btn.onclick = startQuiz;
document.onclick = checkAnswer;
```

Comment: since the issue is about your click handler no longer working show that portion of the code as well. If it is a lot of code recreate the problem with a small example see :[mcve]

Comment: Could `timerStart` also be referring to another interval handle? Do you have others with the same name?

Comment: I added the rest of the relevant code ad tried to slice out the unnecessary details like ids and whatnot for brevity. To clarify, when the answer is clicked it is supposed to display none the question, display correct or incorrect, have a 1 second timeout, then render the next question. once the clear interval is called though, none of that executes onclick as it did before. and I have tried var, let and const for timerStart and it doesn't change the output.

Comment: Can you add the HTML and turn this into a [mcve]? You can use [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: snippet inserted above. I cut out as much as I think I could without changing the functionality. sorry if it's still a lot, I'm still learning and have never used a tool like that before.

Comment: you're most likely getting an error in the console when your quiz stops working, check F12 or the console in whatever browser you're using

Comment: your stack snippet specifically has an error on timeout because you set the `questionCounter` to 4 but there's only 2 questions

Comment: ah, you're right, that's where the problem is. I have more questions in the full code but in trying to get the else condition to fire early on the advanceQuestion function I missed that I was rendering it unable to finish the checkAnswer function. thank you!